# Convert JellyBean to Gingerbread Version Android App

Tags: android

How can I copy a JellyBean app and make it a Gingerbread app? Can anyone please tell me. My app doesn't work on Gingerbread because it was build in ICS.

Comment: You should check your manifest for `min sdk version` support. If it is not 9 or 10, probably your app will not support gingerbread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change ur api version in manifest file..but, when you convert higher to lower means, some higher api version support functionalists will be affect. take care it..

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure about the sdk version numbers, just right click on the project folder, select the option Properties, then you will get project properties window. Select Android option from the left option list. Then it will show the Android Versions and you can select which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Right Click on your Project name** >> **Click on Properties** >> Click on **Android**,  Left side of the Properties Dialog box >> Now checked the check box of **Android 2.3.3**  >> Click on **Apply** >> **OK**

Now in Android manifest file Change the code to

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```